# Kotlin try-catch resumes after catch

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin, try-catch

I don't want to continue code (that opens new activity) if the exception is thrown (if input is empty or invalid). But even if I don't input everything it executes it as if nothing happened. The error is toasted, so it does catch it.

```
try {
        val ip1: String = ip_addr1.text.toString()
        val port1: String = port1.text.toString()
        val ip2: String = ip_addr2.text.toString()
        val port2: String = port2.text.toString()

        // Bind to MyService
        Intent(this, MyService::class.java).also { intent ->
            intent.putExtra("ip1", ip1)
            intent.putExtra("port1", port1)
            intent.putExtra("ip2", ip2)
            intent.putExtra("port2", port2)
            bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
        }

        val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
        showToast("Enter IP in Port")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        showToast(e.toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is in a function that you don’t want to continue, put `return` inside the catch block.

Comment: Also relevant. According to the Kotlin language designers, try/catch is a code smell unless it’s in a low level utility function you’ve made so you don’t have to use it in general application code. https://medium.com/@elizarov/kotlin-and-exceptions-8062f589d07

Answer (score 0):

You have edit texts and get the text from those, you are not transforming any of those to numbers so there is no number format exception to catch. An empty edit text have a valid string text as nothing `""`, then you put that on extra.

If you want to have the numneric value then that will trigger the try catch

```
val ip1 = Integer.parseValue(ip_addr1.text.toString())

//same parsing for the others


Intent(this, MyService::class.java).also { intent ->
            intent.putIntExtra("ip1", ip1)
            //same for the others

...
```

Comment: But in Kotlin, `toIntOrNull()` would be the preferred way to do it.

Comment: I think I want IPs as strings, something like 127.0.0.1 can't be represented as a number I guess.

Comment: That is not a number, the problem with that still remains on my answer, why the try/catch, there is nothing to catch if you are using strings @GeoCap

Comment: Yeah I guess I will need to use something else than try/catch, thanks for clarifying